# While triggering tag command in GIT in ubuntu 16 getting error: unknown non-ascii option in string

Tags: git, tags

While triggering tag command  in GIT in ubuntu 16 getting error: unknown non-ascii option in string.

I am executing a tag command =>
git tag -a version_1.0 commitid -m "tag for release version version_1.0"

Unable to add tag using the above command its showing that => error: unknown non-ascii option in string.

Please guide me how to solve this issue